# OpenXML read excel file with list lookups does not prefilter data

Tags: c#, excel, openxml

I wrote a parser for excel files with openXML. The heart of the code is:

```
using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(filePath, false))
  {
    WorkbookPart workbookPart = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart;
    List<SharedStringItem> stringTable = workbookPart.SharedStringTablePart.SharedStringTable.Elements<SharedStringItem>().ToList();
    Dictionary<string, string> worksheetNames = ReadWorksheetNames(workbookPart);
    result = workbookPart.WorksheetParts.Select(worksheetPart => ParseSheet(worksheetNames[worksheetPart.Uri.OriginalString], worksheetPart.Worksheet, stringTable)).ToList();
  }
```

This works fine with simple excel files. E.g. a file with eight data rows gives me a worksheet with eight data rows. But when list lookups are defined for one columns, the worksheet returns 1048552 rows. How can I filter on the real data only?
It seems that openXML interprets lookups defined on a cell already as data (even so when default value is empty).

Comment: Please post all code, everything seems to be returning an IEnumerable, so you will have the ability to not return so many rows.  If you are using ToList() everywhere that will force the enumeration to be evaluated, and could prompt all records to be returned.  Post all code as an edit to your original question please.

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty will be to add a .Where(...) to your Linq statement that filters out the non empty rows.

```
    result = workbookPart.WorksheetParts
        .Select(worksheetPart => ParseSheet(worksheetNames[worksheetPart.Uri.OriginalString], worksheetPart.Worksheet, stringTable))
        .Where(e => e.Cell1 != string.Empty)
        .ToList();
```

Of course, this will depend on what your ParseSheet() method returns.

Comment: That's what I have now. But since I have 20 worksheets with in total 200 rows, its an overflow to parse more than 20 Mio rows.

Comment: is the ParseSheet method yours? if so please post it.

Comment: Yes it is. But it is not important, because the problem is before.
When my method gets the worksheet it already has 20 mio rows.

   private ExcelWorksheet ParseSheet(string worksheetName,     
   Worksheet worksheet, List<SharedStringItem> stringTable)
   {
      ExcelWorksheet result = new ExcelWorksheet { Name =  
      worksheetName };

      foreach (SheetData sheetData in worksheet.Elements<SheetData>())
      {
        ...